# Custom UIView Placement within Superview

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, subview

I have a custom UIView subclass that needs to be at the bottom of the superview.  I set the view's origin using:

```
CGRect subviewFrame = subview.frame;

CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake(0, superview.bounds.size.height - subviewFrame.size.height);

subviewFrame.origin = newOrigin;

[subview setFrame:subviewFrame];
```

However, this places the subview (origin.y) directly outside of the superview's view frame.

[image: Subview outside of frame]

If I use:

```
CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake(0, superview.bounds.size.height - subviewFrame.size.height * 2.0f);
```

I get the results the I want, which is the subview sitting on the bottom of the window.

[image: Subview inside of frame]

I don't see why I have to multiply the subview's height by 2.

If someone could tell me what I'm missing it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: How about an image to show what you mean. I don't see anything immediately wrong with your code.

Comment: Sure... sorry for the size.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure it has to do with the navBar. Rather than multiplying your view by 2, subtract 44.0 then subtract your subView. And I'm sure you'll get the exact thing you want and understand why.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I also had to subtract 20 for the status bar as well.  I didn't realize I should be using UIScreen applicationFrame: to get the window minus the status bar as well as compensating for the nav bar.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds to get the initial frame, which does not compensate for the status and navigation bars.  UIScreen applicationFrame: returns the frame minus the status bar height.  I use this method and take into account the nav bar height (44.0) to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Useful code to draw bounds of UIView. KADebugShowViewBounds(superview, [UIColor redColor]) and KADebugShowViewBounds(subview, [UIColor redColor]). You will see the bounds of superview and subview in red color. I think the problem should be your layout.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#ifndef KAViewDebugHelper_h
#define KAViewDebugHelper_h

#ifdef DEBUG
#define KADebugShowViewBounds(aView, aColor) \
do \
{ \
    UIColor *color = [(id)aColor isKindOfClass:[UIColor class]] ? aColor : [UIColor redColor]; \
    aView.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor; \
    aView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f; \
} \
while(0)
#else
#define KADebugShowViewBounds(aView)
#endif
#endif
```